# Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead

Tags: python, numpy, deprecated, shapely

I am having hard times to figure out how to solve this warning:

"_*len*_ for multi-part geometries is deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Check the length of the `geoms` property instead to get the  number of parts of a multi-part geometry.
The array interface is deprecated and will no longer work in Shapely 2.0. Convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead."

I tried downgrading shapely to version 1.7.1 but I was not able to. So I am trying to convert the '.coords' to a numpy array instead. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
df_minecoordinates=pd.DataFrame(df_database2.copy())
df_minecoordinates=df_minecoordinates.dropna(subset=['Primary'])
df_minecoordinates=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_minecoordinates, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df_minecoordinates.Longitude, df_minecoordinates.Latitude))
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world = world[(world.pop_est>0) & (world.name!="Antarctica")]
ax = world.plot(color='black', edgecolor='white',figsize=(12, 12),legend=True)
df_minecoordinates['Primary'] = df_minecoordinates['Primary'].astype(str)
df_minecoordinates.plot(column='Primary',ax=ax,markersize=25,legend=True)
plt.show()
```